# How to test for spatial correlation in my data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, spatial

I am new to the realm of spatial statistics, so I need some help.

I have data that locates foreign-owned firms by XY coordinate and domestically-owned firms by XY coordinate.

I have plotted the points on a map in Arc Map.

I want to test the correlation between two maps in other words.

I want to see whether domestically-owned firms are more likely to locate where there is a foreign firm in close proximity i.e. is the location between both sets of firms not independent of one another.

I first thought of Moran's I test, but upon further reflection I am not sure it is appropriate in my case.

Comment: how about setting a test on the pairwise distances between the domestically-owned firms and the foreign firms using Monte-Carlo simulation?

Comment: Okay thanks, I'm not so knowledgable on Monte-Carlo's, but I will investigate that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick answer while on Holiday: This appears to be a question in the realm of spatial point processes, and I would recommend having a look at the R package `spatstat` (which I'm co-developer of). We have also recently published a book which would probably be useful if you have access to that at your library. One option would be to fit a simple Poisson model for the domestic firms with the distance to nearest foreign firm as a covariate. Maybe you can find enough info to do this analysis in our free sample chapter 9, which you can download here:

http://spatstat.github.io/book/sample-chapters.html

Another approach (which may be more or less appropriate depending on the details of your data and analysis) is to use a multitype (also called multivariate) model.